# Problema com retorno de SQL

Tags: sql, query, where

Tenho uma tabela que liga duas outras tabelas. "Solicitação" ela liga "Clientes" e "Solitação_descricao"

Possui a colunas de ligação cliente_id e solicitacao_descricao_id, preciso retornar os clientes que possuem mais de uma solicitação especifica da tabela conforme mostra na figura abaixo.

[image: Demonstrando Tabela]

Eu preciso criar um sql que eu coloque "Where solicitacao_descricao_id = 19 and solicitacao_descricao_id = 8 and solicitacao_descricao_id = 13" e me retorne esse cliente 1. Mas não sei como fazer alguem pode me ajudar? Pq eu quero os clientes que possuem essas 3 solicitacoes juntas. Se eu uso o "OR" me retorna vários que não preciso e o AND não retorna nada!

Comment: Você quer tornar o cliente 1 (```cliente_id```) sem filtrar o mesmo, filtrando apenas pela ```solicitacoes_descricao_id```?

Comment: Com um group by nos cliente_id e só filtrando a solicitação

Comment: Como está a sua query hoje? Como você tentou fazer?

Comment: Fiz as junções das tabelas e dei um Where com os filtros separado por "AND" mas ai ele não retorna nada.. pq não está na msm linha. Não faço ideia como fazer.

Comment: É impossível que o campo `solicitacao_descricao_id` contenha 3 valores distintos simultaneamente (19, 8 e 13). Talvez você queira utilizar `OR` e não `AND`.

Answer (score 0):

Considerando a estrutura de sua tabela, para saber os IDs de clientes que aparecem mais de uma vez em sua tabela "solicitação", você poderia fazer da seguinte forma

```
select cliente_id from solicitacao group by cliente_id HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Você pode usar esta query como base para retornar os nomes dos clientes nesta situação fazendo desta forma:

```
select * from clientes where id in (select cliente_id from solicitacao group by cliente_id HAVING count(*) > 1)
```

Se você quer ver os clientes que aparecem mais de uma vez e as suas solicitações, pode tentar fazer assim:

```
select * from clientes, solicitacao where id = cliente_id and id in (select cliente_id from solicitacao group by cliente_id HAVING count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: Vou tentar. Obrigado